# Trying to understand interthread communication with multiple objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'll first give some context about my little program and then I'll elaborate my question.

**Context:**
I have a program that allows cars to cross a bridge from either **left** or **right**, however, the bridge is so tiny that only one car at the time is able to cross the bridge. Now, in order prevent crashes I implemented a **Controller** class, which ensures only one car is crossing the bridge at the time.

```java
public class BridgeController {

    private boolean isBridgeOccupied = false;

    public synchronized void enterLeft() {
        try {
            while (isBridgeOccupied) {
                wait();
            }
            isBridgeOccupied = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void enterRight() {
        try {
            while (isBridgeOccupied) {
                wait();
            }
            isBridgeOccupied = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void leaveLeft() {
        isBridgeOccupied = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void leaveRight() {
        isBridgeOccupied = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Say there are *1_000_000* cars waiting on either side of the bridge. If I understand my implementation correctly the order of cars, at which they cross the road, should be random. After I executed the program to see how it works I realized that the crossing happens iterative.

R/L display whether a car enters the bridge from **R**ight or **L**eft
Expectation: `RRLLRLRLLLLRLRLLLRLRRRRRRRL` <- R/L are random 
Observation: `RLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLR` <- iterative

Can someone explain me and maybe elaborate on why my code is behaving that way?

Comment: It's probably code you haven't shown us, i.e. it's got nothing to do with the class above.

Comment: `Each Car contains a BridgeController` this worries me.  How many BridgeControlers do you have total?  Surely not one million.

Comment: @markspace My mistake. There's only one `BridgeController`. Also, each `Car` is executed in a `Thread`.. so after creation is up to the Scheduler.

Comment: Show the code that uses this controller.

Comment: Since there is an added delay when switching directions you probably should have a minimum number of cars in one direction before switching. Like in real life.